# how to insert letters in the values of a column with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to insert characters in the values of a column of the data frame with the following conditional.

in values> 999 insert AG0, for example, would be "AG01000", if it is less than <1000 insert AG00, it would be "AG00999"

how to do this using dplyr can someone help me?

I just want to add AG00 in case the column value is 240 = AG00240, or if the value is for example 1040 = AG01040.
I want to always be with 7 characters, not more.

Comment: Try `ifelse(values > 999,"AGO1000", "AGOO999")` or without ifelse `c("AGO1000", "AGO0999")[1 + (values  <= 999)]` with `dplyr`, use `df1 %>% mutate(newcol = case_when(values > 999 ~ "AGO1000", TRUE ~ "AGO0999"))`

Comment: @akrun, I think OP wants the AGO + the actual value. So I would add a `paste` in the `ifelse` statement.

Comment: How about skipping `ifelse` and going with `sprintf("AG%05.0f", c(999,1000))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are five options. You only need one of them, choose whichever matches your expected output and preferences.

```r
library(dplyr)

tibble(values = c(1, 10, 100, 900, 1000, 2000)) %>%
  mutate(
    x1 = sprintf("AG%05.0f", values),
    x2 = paste0(ifelse(values > 999, "AG0", "AG00"), values),
    x3 = paste0(case_when(
      values > 999 ~ "AG0",
      TRUE ~ "AG00"), values),
    x4 = paste0(case_when(
      values > 999 ~ "AG0",
      values > 99 ~ "AG00",
      values > 9 ~ "AG000",
      TRUE ~ "AG0000"), values),
    # suggested by @Frank
    x5 = paste0("AG", strrep("0", 5-nchar(values)), values)
  )
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   values x1      x2      x3      x4      x5     
#    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
# 1      1 AG00001 AG001   AG001   AG00001 AG00001
# 2     10 AG00010 AG0010  AG0010  AG00010 AG00010
# 3    100 AG00100 AG00100 AG00100 AG00100 AG00100
# 4    900 AG00900 AG00900 AG00900 AG00900 AG00900
# 5   1000 AG01000 AG01000 AG01000 AG01000 AG01000
# 6   2000 AG02000 AG02000 AG02000 AG02000 AG02000
```

And if for some reason there are more than a few hundred, perhaps performance is a concern:

```r
set.seed(2)
# Browse[4]> 
bigvalues <- sample(1e4, size=1e3)+1
# Browse[4]> 
head(bigvalues)
# [1] 1850 7025 5734 1682 9436 9432
# Browse[4]> 
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  x1 = sprintf("AG%05.0f", bigvalues),
  x2 = paste0(ifelse(bigvalues > 999, "AG0", "AG00"), bigvalues),
  x3 = paste0(case_when(
    bigvalues > 999 ~ "AG0",
    TRUE ~ "AG00"), bigvalues),
  x4 = paste0(case_when(
    bigvalues > 999 ~ "AG0",
    bigvalues > 99 ~ "AG00",
    bigvalues > 9 ~ "AG000",
    TRUE ~ "AG0000"), bigvalues),
  x5 = paste0("AG", strrep("0", 5-nchar(bigvalues)), bigvalues)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#    x1  548.0  567.95  614.107  603.65  634.55  953.6   100
#    x2 1084.7 1150.90 1239.094 1191.75 1250.60 1854.0   100
#    x3 1018.0 1070.35 1127.585 1104.50 1137.25 1693.2   100
#    x4 1092.6 1144.30 1226.597 1177.20 1224.25 2251.2   100
#    x5 1880.5 1970.15 2058.329 2011.00 2055.60 4035.4   100
```

(Sorry, Frank.)

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow that this is showing 4 ways rather than one really complicated way. Fwiw, one more: `paste0("AG", strrep("0", 5-nchar(values)), values)`

Comment: I want to always be with 7 characters, not more, in your example have values like "AG001"

Comment: Thanks (I think?) for the "sorry". Btw, if there are repeating values, there might be some efficiency issues as well. I posted timings to illustrate here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public I guess DT might be needed to make this fast

Comment: (specifically https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46494926#46494926, for the record)

Comment: ct_zoo$id_animal= paste0("AG", strrep("0", 5-nchar(ct_zoo$id_animal)),
                         ct_zoo$id_animal)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more streamline and more flexible on the fly.

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(values = c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000)) %>% 
   mutate(new_vals = paste0('AG', str_pad(values, 5, side = 'left', pad = '0')))
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#   values new_vals
#    <dbl> <chr>   
# 1      1 AG00001 
# 2     10 AG00010 
# 3    100 AG00100 
# 4   1000 AG01000 
# 5  10000 AG10000
```